# How to ssh to docker image when ran via puppet beaker

Tags: docker, rspec, puppet

So I've written an Puppet Acceptance test using beaker with this Nodeset

```
HOSTS:
  ubuntu-12-04:
    platform: ubuntu-12.04-x64
    image: solarkennedy/ubuntu-12.04-puppet
    hypervisor: docker
CONFIG:
  type: foss
```

And the tests are failing, firstly how do I tell beaker to stop deleting the docker image and secondly how do I ssh onto it, (well i guess if it stops deleting it, i'll just ssh onto the image like normal, but I'll ask just incase)

I know I can turn the logging on to verbose to get more info, but sometimes it's just good to go on the image play around with a few command to work out what needs doing, or checking perms etc without having to re-run the test which takes a while.

Comment: You can manually spin up the container, provision it with Puppet, and then enter it to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but It won't be the same, as the test themselves would execute puppet tasks. I kinda need to see what the tests have done.

Comment: You can still provision it with Puppet yourself instead of letting Beaker do it.

Comment: Are you saying to not use beaker, I mean yea that is one way to do it but it would be nice to use beaker as that's what puppet says to use, and it works nicely with rspec.

Comment: You take Beaker out of the loop to debug, then insert it back in after successful troubleshooting.